# Custom Regex for Parsing Custom Fields in HTML String

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am sending some html in a hidden field, and on server side I would be parsing it with regex. Currently I am able to parse

```
<div id="4059">asd</div>
```

and the code below gives me "id" in match.Groups[2] and "4059" in match.Groups[4], "div" comes at first index and 3rd comes empty.

```
string regex2 = @"<(?<Tag_Name>(a)|div)\b[^>]*?\b(?<URL_Type>(?(1)id))\s*=\s*(?:""(?<URL>(?:\\""|[^""])*)""|'(?<URL>(?:\\'|[^'])*)')";
var matches = Regex.Matches(myDiv, regex2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
var links = new List<string>();
foreach (Match item in matches)
{
  if (item.Groups[2].Value == "div")
     {
       employee.ID = item.Groups[4].Value;
     }
]
```

Can someone please edit this regex,

```
<(?<Tag_Name>(a)|div)\b[^>]*?\b(?<URL_Type>(?(1)id))\s*=\s*(?:""(?<URL>(?:\\""|[^""])*)""|'(?<URL>(?:\\'|[^'])*)')
```

so that I could parse

```
<div id="5094" fieldA="asd" fieldB="def" fieldC="ghi"></div>
```

and the fields could be added too.

*I should also mention here that I am working on a custom control and I CAN NOT USE HTML AGILITY PACK as the assemblies conflict as I add this in my project.*

Comment: Instead of the HTML Agility Pack, try [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) as a parser.

Comment: the problem with an implemented parser is that i am including my custom attributes to the tags, can parser consider that?

Comment: Why are you using HTML to transmit data from client to server? Can't you use the URL or hidden input fields for that?

Comment: It should. Custom attributes are fine in HTML - there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that the string contains only `<div field="value" field="value" ...></div>` (i.e. there's nothing but this div in the string), then just simplify your regex to pick out the field and value, and run it in a loop:

```
string regstr = @"\s+(?<field>[^\s=]+)\s*=\s*\"(?<value>[^\"]+)\"";
var reg = new Regex(regstr);
var m = reg.Match(myDiv);
while (m.Success)
{
    // m.Groups["field"] and m.Groups["value"] hold your field and value
    // get the next match
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```